# Typescript internal function call not working

Tags: typescript, function

I'm using Typescript and have a class. within that class I have a constructor and method, but I cant seem to call that method within the body of the function:

```js
import  { ParentPlayer } from './parentPlayer'
import ws = require('ws')

export class MasterSocket{

    constructor(masterPlayer:ParentPlayer, serverPort:number, Notifier:any) {
       createPipeline(masterPlayer,serverPort,Notifier)
    }

    function createPipeline(masterPlayer:ParentPlayer, serverPort:number, Notifier:any){
    if(masterPlayer !== null)
      {
        const wss:ws.Server = new ws.Server({ port: serverPort})
        wss.on('connection', function connection(svr) {
            Notifier.emit('test','Pipeline established')

            svr.onmessage = (msg) =>
            {
                Notifier.emit('test','Message received at Pipeline: ' + msg)
            }

            svr.onclose = (evt) =>
            {
                Notifier.emit('test','Backend: Pipeline Closed: ' + evt.reason)
     >>>>>>>    createPipeline(masterPlayer,serverPort,Notifier)
            }

            svr.on('message', function incoming(message) {
            Notifier.emit('test','message received from: ' + message)
            })

          svr.send('this is a message sent from the Pipeline');
        })
      }
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As peinearydevelopment has already mentioned, you need to remove the `function` keyword in order for `createPipeline` to be an actual *method* of the class.

But you also need to convert your `onConnection` callback to an arrow function in order to preserve the `this` context of the class (more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
wss.on('connection', connection(svr) => {
    // ...

    svr.onclose = (evt) => {
        Notifier.emit('test', 'Backend: Pipeline Closed: ' + evt.reason)
        this.createPipeline(masterPlayer, serverPort, Notifier)
    }
    //...
});
```

Comment: Okay this is what worked...thank you: wss.on('connection', svr => {